# Monodroid - Change Constructor Visibility using Metadata

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm currently porting the Facebook SDK for Android to a C# library. I am trying to change the WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder constructor visibility metadata using metadata bindings described here:

[http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_%28.jar%29)

Does anybody know how to change the constructor visibility from protected to public?

```
protected FeedDialogBuilder(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record - to change the visibility you would add to Transforms/Metadata.xml something like:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='Name_of_the_package']/class[@name='FeedDialogBuilder']/method[@name='FeedDialogBuilder']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```